# How was Rabbi Yochanan allowed to walk with his son's bone?

Tags: death, funeral-burial-levaya, tractate-brachot

It says in [Brachos 5B](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=5b&format=pdf) that R' Yochanan used to show people his tenth son's bone (all of his children passed away, and he used to carry a bone of his tenth child).

How was he allowed to not bury this bone?

Comment: I'm guessing this has something to do with [ossuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossuary) style burials.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the Q&A cited in [yydl's answer to a related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10212/37):

Rashi to Berachos there says that it was a piece less than the size of a barleycorn, which isn't subject to tum'ah and therefore doesn't require burial. Aruch, and Rashbam to Bava Basra 116a (both cited in Mesores Hashas to Berachos there) explain that it was a tooth, which according to many posekim doesn't require burial either.

Aside from this, some other commentaries ([cited in the back of the Nehardea edition of Berachos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37952&pgnum=457)) explain the phrase differently, as "a bone from the bereavement meal (סעודת הבראה)." According to this approach, it wasn't a human bone at all.

Comment: The only reason a body part requires kevura is to avoid spreading tumah?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it looks like there's a dispute about this point. R. Chanoch (Heinrich) Ehrentreu of Munich (grandfather of Dayan Chanoch Ehrentreu, יבלח"ט) [argued](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=818&pgnum=19) that indeed Rashi is implying that a fragment of bone this small doesn't require burial; R. Meir Lerner of Altona took sharp issue with this, and [argued](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47562&pgnum=167) that indeed even larger pieces (short of a complete skull and most of the rest of the body) may not require it.